# java StringTokenizer skips the charaters if its part of delimiter

Tags: java, string

I have issues in using java string tokenizer:

```
String myString = "1||2||3|||4";

StringTokenizer stp = new StringTokenizer(myString, "||");
while (stp.hasMoreTokens()) {
    System.out.println(stp.nextToken());
}
```

actual output : `[1,2,3,4]`

expected output : `[1,2,3,'|4']`

Could any one help me on the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
    String myString = "1||2||3|||4";
    String[] s=myString.split("\\|\\|");
    for (String string : s) {
        System.err.println(string);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks rameshj for your time. Its save my time a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot do anything because it's how `StringTokenizer` works (you can put `returnDelims` true and remove it manually but it's more hard than look sometimes)

```
String myString = "1||2||3|||4";

String[] tokens = myString.split("\\|\\|");
for(String token : tokens)
{
    System.out.println(token);
}
```

You can use split which does what you want.

Output:

> 1
>
> 2
>
> 3
>
> |4

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to use the split method of the String class for doing this since StringTokenizer matches the given string and split takes a regular expression. I would use this:

```
String[] splitStr = myString.split("[|]{2}");
```

This matches every time the regular expression [|] (a single pipe) is matched twice in a row.

Comment: Your code is also works thanks for your time and for your different approach :)

Answer (score 0):

You are maybe thinking of [String.split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-), as this splits on a *delimiter string*.

A `StringTokenizer` takes the delimiter string and recognizes *all characters* in it as a delimiter. So in fact you redundantly specified the "|" character a second time.

Using the split function is what you maybe wanted:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString("1||2||3|||4".split("\\|\\|")));
```

This produces

> [1, 2, 3, |4]

Comment: Thanks Seelenvirtuose :)

Answer (score 0):

take a look this is an easy solution:

```
StringTokenizer stp = new StringTokenizer(myString, "|");
        while (stp.hasMoreTokens()) {
            System.out.println(stp.nextToken());
        }
```